# Set Relative Layout to same heights as scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with a couple of different Layouts/scroll views etc. Currently, my Scroll view is set to a fixed height. But even though I've set the Layout to be the same height as the Scroll view, the Scroll view is cutting off my horizontal scroll view at the bottom of the screen.

Can anybody shed some light on how to make the Layout height the same as the Scroll view?

My end goal is to have: an image pinned to the top of the screen, the Horizontal Scroll View pinned to the bottom of the screen, and the Scroll view to take up whatever space is left.

Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".HomeScreen"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelLayoutTitleImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/titleimage"
        android:src="@drawable/saferroadsshellharbourtitle"
        android:layout_weight="0.08" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="272dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="272dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_Old_logo"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/oldlogomenu"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_report_a_hazard"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Old_logo"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/reportahazardmenu"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_report_a_hazard"
            android:id="@+id/btn_Council_Website"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/councilwebsitemenu"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_Council_Website"
            android:id="@+id/btn_dob_in_a_hoon"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/dobinahoonmenu"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        >


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
             android:id="@+id/facebook"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/facebookbutton"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
            android:id="@+id/twitter"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/scclogoold"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/twitter"
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/contactbutton"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I would assume that your ScrollView could be set to `layout_height=wrap_content`.

Comment: @emerssso if I do that, won't it completely block the Horizontal scroll view at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Yes, you are completely correct. I should have said "the RelativeLayout in the ScrollView".

Comment: @emerssso that is the right idea, but i want it the other war around - ie i want the **relative layout** height to be the same as the **scrollView** height

Comment: Tried to set the relative layouts height to match_parent if the parent has a set height? You could do that with a linear layout instead of a relative layout and include weights for your imagebuttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Now the whole Horizontal scroll view at the bottom has been covered up by the vertical scroll view.

Comment: never mind - I was using the wrong view. Your answer is correct. Thanks!